# how to call post api recursively untill array.length condition is false

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, rest

Here is my question how to call recusive post api function untill array.length condition is false

**Here is my code what i tried**

```
const postItemArray =["<eg:cat>"]
var collectionDataContainer = [];



const recurseFunction = i => {
    const [loadingStatus, mainData, addDataToPostItemArray] = useFetch(`http//blabla${postItemArray[i]}variety`);
    console.log(edgeData[i]);

    if (i < postItemArray.length) {
      recurseFunction(i + 1);
    }
     if (addDataToPostItemArray.length !== 0) {
      postItemArray.push(...addDataToPostItemArray);
     }
    if (mainData.length !== 0) {
      collectionDataContainer.push(...demoData);
    }
    console.log(DummyArray);
  };

  recurseFunction(0);
```

here the parameters in useTetch are

`loadingStatus` will give `true` or `false` condition

`mainData` will give `Data` after fetching

`addDataToPostItemArray` fitered out mainData and  will give array of `keys` if MainData have any keys for next loop recursion

**Here is the Example Data format for understanding before calling recursive function**

`step-1`
initially `postItemArray = ["<eg:cat>"]`
after passing `postItemArray[i]` value to useFetch then we will get data like this

```
mainData=[
          {key : "<eg:dog>",class : "animal"},
          {key : "<eg:ant>",class : "insect"},
          {key : "<eg:monkey>", category : "jumping"},
          {key : "<eg:fish>", category : "swim"}
         ]
```

`step-2` `addDataToPostItemArray` this array will find out the class object keys if mainData have class key value pair inside the useFetch and collect the key in the format of below

```
addDataToPostItemArray =["<eg:dog>","<eg:ant>"]
```

if mainData array object have class Key it will catch and element store the keys inside the `addDataToPostItemArray`

here is the logic done in useFetch file for finding keys

```
axios(config).then(response => {
 let originalResult = response.data.results.bindings
              .filter(ek => ek.Class !== undefined && ek)
              .map(el => el.key);

               setFindClass(originalResult);
```

but my problem is im able to get the keys from useFetch and pushed into the `postItemArray`

and `postItemArray` length will exceeds to `3` as we expected

but in inside the  `recurseFuction` `if statement(i < postItemArray.length)` condition looping only one time because its cosidering same initial length  after pushed some data to `postItemArray`

so that why im not able to get looping data after array length is increased
this is my fail condition

```
 if (i < postItemArray.length) {
          recurseFunction(i + 1);
        }
```

**please anyone can help me out please im unable to find the solution for this question**

just only i want to collect the Data into this container `collectionDataContainer = []`
looping if mainData have class and key object

**if any one have better logic please help me out that is soo appreciatable**

Comment: sorry for may bad demoData = mainData on code

Comment: There's too much here without context for me to be able to give you a good answer. I think you should try to simplify your issue.

Comment: Let us try not using the `postItemArray` (which is common for all recursions). Instead of that, use an alternative array, say `piArray` which will be like this: `const recurseFunction = (i, piArray) => {...`. And the first call to recursion will be `recurseFunction(0, []);`. And this condition: `if (i < postItemArray.length)` needs to change. But, it's not clear how.

Comment: `@jsN00b` can you reform the above code for me please i tried with `3 arguments` in `recurseFunction` I'm unable to achive the perfect logic